# receiving a debug error when attempting to run program

Tags: c++

I am receiving the following debug error when attempting to run the first part of my program:

> Debug Error!
>
> Program:
>   ...\user\desktop\PunchLineProgram\Debug\PunchLineProgram.exe
>   Module: 
>   ...\user\desktop\PunchLineProgram\Debug\PunchLineProgram.exe
>
> File:
>   Run-Time Check Failure #3 - T
>   (Press Retry to debug the application)

I am attempting to have the user select whether they want to hear a joke, running and if\else statement that will output a message to the user, based on their response. If I comment out these statements, I do not receive the error when attempting to run the program. I know I'm probably missing something simple, as I am a novice. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
/*Include Section*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

/*Namespace Section*/
using namespace std;

/*Function Prototypes Section*/
void displayAllLines(ifstream &infile);
void displayLastLine(ifstream &infile);

/*Main section: this is the entry point of the program, which controls the flow of execution*/
int main()
{
    string file1;
    string file2;
    ifstream joke;
    ifstream punchline;
    int decision;
    char y;
    char n;

    cout << "*******************************************************************************" << endl;
    cout << setw(48) << "Punchline Program" << endl;
    cout << "*******************************************************************************" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to the Punchline Program!" << endl;
    cout << "Are you ready to hear a joke? (y or n):  ";
    cin >> decision;

    if (decision == y)
    {
        cout << "Great! Let's get started!" << endl;
    }

    else if (decision == n)
    {
        cout << "Ah, no sense of humor, I see. Time to make like a tree and leaf (queue rimshot)!" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing to char you should use '':
char answer

```
if (answer == 'y') { *//this only checks for LOWER case y*
cout << "You selected Yes" << endl;
}
```

when comparing to a string use ""
int/float/double... you can just use the variable.

Besides that, your **decision** variable as int when it should be char, and you don't need char **y** nor **n**. (you yourself never even used it in that code)

I'd suggest looking up c++ tutorials, most show and explain the different between char/string, ' and ".

Comment: Thank you for the information, Greg! I will look these up. I updated the code to use char answer and it is now working. I appreciate your help!